# I'm making requests via the terminal to an API, and I want to render the responses on the frontend to interact with them However I'm facing this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, vite

I am a beginner programmer, and I have worked with APIs before. However, this is the first time I have encountered this error. Previously, when I tried to render directly in the browser, I faced CORS errors, but now I understand why CORS is an issue. So, I thought that if I made the request from a server and simply tried to render the response, it would work. However, I encountered this error, and I don't know what to do.

The error I'm facing:

> Module "https" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "https.Agent" in client code.

I will show the code where I make the request and the home page where I try to render the response
and the API is working I can make requests using Postman and via the terminal. I just can't use the response from the request on the frontend.

```
getChamados.js

import axios from "axios"
import https from "https"

const headers = {
  key: "TOKEN", 
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
}


const correiosApiUrl = "URL_API"

const getCorreiosData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(correiosApiUrl, {
      headers: headers,
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
    })

    console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erro ao acessar a API dos Correios:", error.message)
  }
}

getCorreiosData()
export default getCorreiosData
```

```
home.jsx

import axios from "axios"

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

import getCorreiosData from "./getChamados"

import "./Home.css"

const Home = () => {
  const [correiosData, setCorreiosData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    getCorreiosData().then((data) => {
      setCorreiosData(data)
    })
  })

  return <div> Home </div>
}

export default Home
```

I expected the response on the console.

Comment: `getCorreiosData` should have `return response;`.

Comment: Try removing the `httpsAgent` property from the Axios header. I think adding that header exposes some security risks.

Comment: when i remove httpsAgent i face this error 'unable to verify the first certificate'